# Could not resolve collision collision between" Cyrillic_General_CI_AS "and" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS "in EXCEPT operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, odbc

At the moment there is a need to see the difference between tables from different databases. Now there is a PostgreSQL database, which runs in a docker container, and an SQL Server database, which is deployed locally on the machine. An ODBC driver is configured in SQL Server for inter-database communication. I am writing a query:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
except
select * from [ODBC_NAME].[PG_DATABASE_NAME].[PG_SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME]
```

In some cases it works, but intermittently crashes the error:

> Could not resolve collision collision between" Cyrillic_General_CI_AS "and" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS "in EXCEPT operation.

I also found out that this table in SQL Server has different COLLATION fields, and in PostgreSQL the COLLATION is not specified at all in the same table. I tried to create a new database in PostgreSQL with lc_collate and lc_ctype "ru_RU". The error remains.

Comment: Have you tried `select column1 collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS from TABLE_NAME` etc i.e. collate each column in both queries so they match.

Comment: Yes. With EXCEPT it crahses, but the query to PostgreSQL itself runs ok.
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES" reported an error. The vendor did not provide information about the error.

Comment: You must find a collation in PostGreSQL that match the standard codepage used by SQL Server that runs with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (codepage 1252)

Answer (score 0):

I found some decision.
I just write
`select column1 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, column2 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS from table1`
even when column1 and column2 have same collation (and my database has Cyrillic_General_CI_AS collation). This way a can compare tables with EXCEPT without any errors.